# Installing weblate 2.3: from django.db.models.sql.aggregates ImportError: No module named aggregates

Tags: python, django, pip, importerror, weblate

While installing [weblate](https://weblate.org/en/) 2.3 (older version), I had the following error:

> File "/srv/weblate/weblate/trans/boolean_sum.py", line 27, in
>   
>       from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Sum as BaseSQLSum ImportError: No module named aggregates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at my django version, and it was the latest one, which doesn't have a `aggregates.py` in [`django/db/models/sql/`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models/sql). I took a look at [weblate 2.3 's `requirements.txt`](https://github.com/nijel/weblate/blob/weblate-2.3/requirements.txt#L1) and it contains the following line:

```
Django>=1.7
```

This was installing `1.10`. I changed the line to

```
Django==1.7
```

Installed the right version with `pip` and now everything works as expected.
Hope it helps someone else. :)

Similar problem could also happen in weblate 2.7 and higher as their `requirements.txt` still uses `>=` on [`master`](https://github.com/nijel/weblate/blob/master/requirements.txt#L1) and on [`weblate-2.7`](https://github.com/nijel/weblate/blob/weblate-2.7/requirements.txt#L1) tag.